# How to dynamically choose the return type of the operator [ ] in composite design pattern?

Tags: c++11, design-patterns, dynamic, polymorphism, composite

First of all, I want to point out that it is the first time I am using dynamic polymorphism and the composite design pattern.

I would like to use the composite design pattern to create a `class Tree` which is able to take different objects of the type `Tree`, a composite type, or `Leaf`, an atomic type. Both Tree and Leaf inherit from a common class `Nature`. Tree can store Leaf or Tree objects into a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nature>> children`. I would like to fill the vector `children` with a syntax of this kind (so I guess I have to use variadic, to consider a generic number of inputs in the input lists), as in the following:

```
Leaf l0(0);
Leaf l1(1);
Tree t0;
Tree t1;
t0.add(l0,l1);
t1.add(t0,l0,l1); // or in general t1.add(t_00,...,t_0n, l_00,...,l_0n,t10,...,t1n,l10,...,l1n,.... )
```

Then I would also access different elements of a `Tree` by means of the `operator[ ]`. So for example `t1[0]` returns `t0` and `t1[0][0]` returns `l0`, while `t1[0][1]` returns `l0`.

Also I would like an homogeneous behaviour. So either use `->` or the dot for accessing the methods on all levels (tree or leaf).

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

The implementation of such classes can be like the following:

```
class Nature
{
  public:
    virtual void nature_method() = 0;
    virtual~Nature();
    //virtual Nature& operator[] (int x);

};
class Leaf: public Nature
{
    int value;
  public:
    Leaf(int val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
    void nature_method() override
    {
        std::cout << " Leaf=="<<value<<" ";
    }
}; 
class Tree: public Nature
{ 
    private:
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr< Nature > > children;
    int value;

    public:
    Tree(int val)
    {
        value = val;
    }


     void add(const Nature&);

     void add(const Leaf& c)
    {
        children.push_back(std::make_shared<Leaf>(c));
    } 

     void add(const Tree& c)
    {
        children.push_back(std::make_shared<Tree>(c));
    }   


    void add(std::shared_ptr<Nature> c)
    {
        children.push_back(c);
    }

     template<typename...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<0==sizeof...(Args), void>::type
    add(const Leaf& t,Args...more)
    {
     children.push_back(std::make_shared<Leaf>(t));
    };

    template<typename...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<0==sizeof...(Args), void>::type
    add(const Tree& t,Args...more)
    {
     children.push_back(std::make_shared<Tree>(t));
    };


    template<typename...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<0<sizeof...(Args), void>::type
    add(const Leaf& t,Args...more)
    {
      children.push_back(std::make_shared<Leaf>(t));
      add(more...);
    };

    template<typename...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<0<sizeof...(Args), void>::type
    add(const Tree& t,Args...more)
    {
      children.push_back(std::make_shared<Tree>(t));
      add(more...);
    };

    void nature_method() override
    {
        std::cout << " Tree=="<< value;
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
          children[i]->nature_method();
    }
}
```

I could implement the overload `operator []` to return a pointer to Nature or a Nature object, like so:

```
 Nature& operator[] (int x) {
        return *children[x];
    }

 std::shared_ptr< Nature > operator[] (int x) {
        return children[x];
    }
```

In both cases, the return type is `Nature` related. This because it could be a `Leaf` or a `Tree`, which is not known in advance. But since the return type of the operator has to be known at compile time, I cannot do something else.

However, if the returned type would be `Tree` related, I cannot use  the `operator []` anymore, because I have enforced it to be `Nature`.

How can I dynamically choose the return type, `Tree` or `Leaf` related, of `[]`? Is there any workaround for this?

I could consider `operator []` a virtual method in the Nature class, but still I would no what to make out of this.

I have read about covariant types as well, but I do not know if they would be applicable here.

Thank you.

Comment: Your architecture feels like your inheritance is not correct. They are not working together properly, so you probably want to go back to the drawing board, as what you want to achieve is not possible in C++ in a clean way. Even if you make [] virtual, the fat is that `Nature` returns a `Nature`, and even if the child returns something else, what you get is a `Nature`. Look at the explanation of virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be type-safe, the return value of `[]` will have to be checked at each use site to determine if it is a `Tree` or a `Leaf`.

You could also choose not to be type-safe, and invoke undefined behaviour if you use a `Leaf` in a way that is supposed to be a `Tree`.

Regardless:

```
virtual Nature& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) {
  throw std::invalid_argument("Not a Tree");
}
virtual Nature const& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) const {
  throw std::invalid_argument("Not a Tree");
}
```

in `Nature`, followed by:

```
virtual Nature& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) final override {
  auto r = children.at((std::size_t)x);
  if (r) return *r;
  throw std::out_of_range("no element there");
}
virtual Nature const& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) const final override {
  auto r = children.at((std::size_t)x);
  if (r) return *r;
  throw std::out_of_range("no element there");
}
```

in `Tree`.

That'll spawn exceptions when you use `[]` on the wrong type.